# JavaScript proxy: Simple log function that will proxy an string argument to the console.log()

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

I'm new to JavaScript and learning it for a week now. I had applied for an internship in different companies and I was called yesterday for an interview. They asked me some questions and for this one particular question, I had no clue. Can someone provide me the solution or help me clarify this proxy topic.

What is the solution to this Question?

Please write a simple log function that will proxy a string argument to console.log() *

Comment: Strictly speaking "proxy" is a noun and not a verb, so this question is a bit weird.

Comment: `Proxy` is basically a something that intercepts an interaction with an underlying function or property and adds some extra logic to the underlying function or property before invoking/changing/returning that value to the caller. This question is quite ambiguous and more explanation is required for a better answer. You should have asked follow up questions regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

If I were asked this question I would understand *"that will proxy a string"* to mean *"that will pass on a string ... in a controlled way"*. Wikipedia writes about the [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern):

> #### What problems can the Proxy design pattern solve?
>
> - The access to an object should be controlled.
> - Additional functionality should be provided when accessing an object.

So in this case you would *verify* that the argument is a string, or another interpretation could be that you would convert a non-string to string before passing it on to `console.log`. So I think the following two answers would be OK:

```js
function log(str) {
    if (typeof str !== "string") throw new TypeError("log should not be called with a non-string");
    console.log(str);
}

log("hello");
```

Or:

```js
function log(str) {
    if (typeof str !== "string") str = JSON.stringify(str);
    console.log(str);
}

log(["an", "array"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

**

```js
function log(){
    console.log(...arguments);
}
log("a", "b")
```

**

Comment: Your answer maybe what the OP is looking for but, it has no explanation and does not address the fact that you are interpreting proxy as a simple "wrapper" around a function. Add more explanation and check the answer by @trincot to see how to write a good answer to question